# Page Viewer Web Part not working

Tags: 2010, web-part

I am using a page viewer web part to display linkedin on my sharepoint site. When i use this web part on my sharepoint stand alone server everything works just fine. When i try it on my sever farm however, the web part remains blank.

-I have a dutch language pack installed on the farm.

-Browser file handling is set to permissive. (Maybe irrelevant)

Any questions and/or ideas?

**Edit**

-The web part does show on any other computer than my own and one colleague, the main difference here is that we use IE9, could that be the problem and does anyone have prior experience with this.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? The page errors out? Is the server connected to the internet? Did you try it with a page on the server?

Comment: Also, are you hitting Production from your desktop or are you using a browser on the production server to test with?

Comment: @Kit Menke, I didn't say not working, the whole web part "remains blank" It just doesnt load the web page. How do you mean try with a page on the server? thx

Comment: @Dave Wise I am hitting it from my desktop. When i hit it from the production server it works, I forgot some important details yesterday (end of the day you knwo the feeling) i will add them to my post now.